# SAP BW process chain Run-time vs Duration

Tags: sap-bw

I can't determine what each of these columns mean in transaction Code `RSPCM`.

For example I had a Process chain finish after **6 hours** of starting, Duration said **6 hours** but Run-time was **1.9 hours**.

In another Process chain Run-time was **18 hours** but Duration was only about **6 hours**. One is bigger then the other but not always so I can't figure out what time measurement they refer to.

[image]

Comment: A guess: duration equals end time - start time, and runtime is total sum of effective run of all parallel processes in the current system (excluding extraction time in source system i.e. duration can be 1 hour but runtime can be 10 minutes if extraction runs for 50 minutes in source system); including sum of parallel processes i.e. if duration is 1 hour and execution runs in 2 parallel processes, runtime could be 2 hours).

Comment: This sounds somewhat reasonable, I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @SandraRossi You were absolutely right with the duration, but with run-time it was failed processes not extraction. but your comment was a really helpful insight so thank you.

Comment: By the way, I think this question is more for **superuser.com** than for stackoverflow because it's not related to coding nor to a developer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After observing multiple process chains for a while (both failed and successful ones) I found the difference to be the following.

Run-time is the sum of the time each ***Successful*** sub process ran regardless if parallel or not.

Duration is "End time - Start time" Including failed processes.